# Winning, winnings, win or ...?

Tags: terminology

I am looking for the exact term that describes the amount of money won with a single bet. Something like:

> I bet on that team and I won. My winning(s?) for that bet is (are?) 50$

I need this for the name of a field in a database therefore, I don't need long elegant sentences, just the correct term.

Now, for something even more difficult, I also need the name for the taxes payed on that amount. Is that Winnings Tax, Winnings Taxes, other combinations?

Comment: Different flavours of English could use different terms for these amounts. Do you have a particular variety of English in mind?

Comment: They are *winnings*, and you pay the *tax on the winnings*. If you're referring to a tax that only applies to winnings, you can call it a *winnings tax*.

Comment: I am editing some sort of user manual, technical reference... I would say the flavour of english that I need is "technical". I will go for Lawrence's "winnings tax". Thank you

Comment: @Lawrence, please post that as an answer the OP can accept :)

Comment: @WillCrawford Done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are *winnings* and you pay the *tax on the winnings*. If you’re referring to a tax that only applies to the winnings, you can call it a *winnings tax*.

> **winnings** *noun*
>   Money won, especially by gambling.
>   ‘he went to collect his winnings’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/winning)

Comment: Ironically enough, I'm pretty sure the fact that it's a plural stems from a time when people would collect the outcome of several bets at once. I've never seen "winning" used in the singular to refer to a single bet though. [Not an objection, I've voted for the answer :o)]

Answer (score -1):

Since you are writing for a **technical manual**, I would suggest you to use simpler terms,

> Amount Won | Tax Payable